# How to normalize across different clusters

Tags: normalization

So I have the following data, my question is what's the best way to normalize to be able to tell which ethnicities dominate.

Do I divide roughly by "countries in that ethnicities" ? Or do I divide by total number of each ethnicity (which I can't find easily)... or divide by total number of ethnicities within each field?

Physics

undergrad Ethnicity Distribution:

511 Asian,GreaterEastAsian,EastAsian
3 Asian,GreaterEastAsian,Japanese
81 Asian,IndianSubContinent
2 GreaterAfrican,Africans
4 GreaterAfrican,Muslim
84 GreaterEuropean,British
4 GreaterEuropean,EastEuropean
6 GreaterEuropean,Jewish
7 GreaterEuropean,WestEuropean,French
3 GreaterEuropean,WestEuropean,Germanic
5 GreaterEuropean,WestEuropean,Hispanic
3 GreaterEuropean,WestEuropean,Italian

Grad ethnicity distribution:

277 Asian,GreaterEastAsian,EastAsian
20 Asian,GreaterEastAsian,Japanese
169 Asian,IndianSubContinent
18 GreaterAfrican,Africans
59 GreaterAfrican,Muslim
206 GreaterEuropean,British
55 GreaterEuropean,EastEuropean
57 GreaterEuropean,Jewish
31 GreaterEuropean,WestEuropean,French
27 GreaterEuropean,WestEuropean,Germanic
35 GreaterEuropean,WestEuropean,Hispanic
35 GreaterEuropean,WestEuropean,Italian
11 GreaterEuropean,WestEuropean,Nordic

Sustainable Energy:

Undergrad Ethnicity Distribution:

183 Asian,GreaterEastAsian,EastAsian
46 Asian,IndianSubContinent
12 GreaterAfrican,Muslim
327 GreaterEuropean,British
9 GreaterEuropean,EastEuropean
5 GreaterEuropean,Jewish
2 GreaterEuropean,WestEuropean,French
4 GreaterEuropean,WestEuropean,Germanic

Grad Ethnicity Dist:

100 Asian,GreaterEastAsian,EastAsian
8 Asian,GreaterEastAsian,Japanese
67 Asian,IndianSubContinent
17 GreaterAfrican,Africans
28 GreaterAfrican,Muslim
191 GreaterEuropean,British
27 GreaterEuropean,EastEuropean
23 GreaterEuropean,Jewish
34 GreaterEuropean,WestEuropean,French
21 GreaterEuropean,WestEuropean,Germanic
26 GreaterEuropean,WestEuropean,Hispanic
22 GreaterEuropean,WestEuropean,Italian
9 GreaterEuropean,WestEuropean,Nordic
2 unknown

Mechanical Engineering:

Undergrad Ethnicity Distribution:

236 Asian,GreaterEastAsian,EastAsian
2 Asian,GreaterEastAsian,Japanese
44 Asian,IndianSubContinent
6 GreaterAfrican,Muslim
418 GreaterEuropean,British
13 GreaterEuropean,EastEuropean
4 GreaterEuropean,Jewish
4 GreaterEuropean,WestEuropean,French
2 GreaterEuropean,WestEuropean,Germanic
8 GreaterEuropean,WestEuropean,Hispanic
6 GreaterEuropean,WestEuropean,Italian
2 GreaterEuropean,WestEuropean,Nordic
2 unknown

Grad ethnicity distribution:

143 Asian,GreaterEastAsian,EastAsian
29 Asian,GreaterEastAsian,Japanese
96 Asian,IndianSubContinent
17 GreaterAfrican,Africans
41 GreaterAfrican,Muslim
239 GreaterEuropean,British
46 GreaterEuropean,EastEuropean
68 GreaterEuropean,Jewish
31 GreaterEuropean,WestEuropean,French
15 GreaterEuropean,WestEuropean,Germanic
21 GreaterEuropean,WestEuropean,Hispanic
27 GreaterEuropean,WestEuropean,Italian
13 GreaterEuropean,WestEuropean,Nordic
18 unknown

Comment: It depends, what do you want to use the results for? If you can split by local students and international students, you could normalize by the ethic proportions locally and globally.

Comment: I want to show which ethnicity dominates the undergrads in each field.

Comment: If 80% of the student population is Nordic, but 90% of the country is Nordic, does that mean the Nordic students 'dominate'? You could say they do based on the fact that a randomly chosen student is very likely to be Nordic, or you could say that they are underrepresented. There is no objective answer here. Yet which one you choose very much affects what normalization method you should choose.